# Jenkins need Gradle input to remove Java heap Space error

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy

I am executing a Groovy application using Gradle and getting a error regarding "Java heap Space". After applying this code inside my build.gradle file it works fine without error.

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
  configure(groovyOptions.forkOptions) {
    memoryMaximumSize = ‘1g’
    jvmArgs = [‘-XX:MaxPermSize=512m’, ‘-Xms512m’, ‘-Xmx1g’]
  }
}
```

But I want to build this application from Jenkins. I can't change build.gradle file because Jenkins download the code from git and execute the build. So, I want to apply something from jenkins settings which will increase the heap size to remove the error.
Following [Builds failing with OutOfMemoryErrors](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Builds+failing+with+OutOfMemoryErrors) applied this values `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms512m -Xmx1g` but still getting the error.

I am not understanding how should I apply above code inside Jenkins to remove 'Java heap error'

Comment: Have you run the build with the `-d` debug option to see which settings are actually used?

Comment: I have used -d option like this `gradle -d clean distZip distTar groovydoc` but from console output I can't understand which option used. because it's huge debug data is generated. can you please describe what does my above gradle code mean which I used in build.gradle file ?

Comment: What about redirecting the command's output to a file: `gradle ... > debug.log`, opening it in a text editor of your choice and searching for `-XX` or the like?

Comment: Inside project directory I haven't found any debug.log file

Comment: Did you look into `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace` or `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`, depending on your _Configure System_ → _Workspace Root Directory_?

Comment: Put these options in your gradlew file GRADLE_OPTS= -Xmx512m
JAVA_OPTS= -Xmx512m

Comment: @Mrunal As I have already mentioned in my post that I can't change anything in disk project directory. According your commant I know if I write something in gradle.build file or in gradlew file that solved the problem. But what I really want is I want to apply some option in Jenkins